# How to have Twilio calling the agent and calling the customer, and connecting them to talk to each other

Tags: asp.net, twilio

That's a very very simple situation but I could not find a solution for it.

I am using ASP.NET Webforms and C# to build a system that allows this scenario:

An agent pulls up a customer account to see what his phone number is. The phone number appears as a link on the agent screen. The agent clicks on the link. Twilio places a call to the agent (Twilio already knows the agent's phone number by his login). The agent picks up the phone. Twilio calls the customer (the caller id is the company number). The customer picks up the phone. Twilio connects them together, and they talk.

By doing this, the customer won't see the agent's phone number.

Please notice that, we don't have desk phones, we use company issued iPhone so we don't leave our iPhone at work during the night.

Comment: I got a downvote but don't know why. If you downvote my question, please state the reason. We're here to learn together, that person didn't share his thought or knowledge but just a downvote, did it not make any senses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use call controller and connect both ends.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ClickToCall.Web.Services;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;

namespace ClickToCall.Web.Controllers
{
    public class CallController : TwilioController
    {
        private readonly IRequestValidationService _requestValidationService;
    public CallController() : this(new RequestValidationService())
    {
    }

    public CallController(IRequestValidationService requestValidationService)
    {
        _requestValidationService = requestValidationService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Connect(string salesNumber)
    {
        var twilioAuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];
        if (!_requestValidationService.IsValidRequest(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, twilioAuthToken))
        {
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response
            .Say("Thanks for contacting our sales department. Our " +
                 "next available representative will take your call.")
            .Dial(salesNumber)
            .Hangup();

        return TwiML(response);
    }
}
}
```

More details refer : https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-csharp-mvc

Comment: It is a little trickier when I implemented this method in WebForms (not MVC). I got it worked anyway. Thanks!